# Exploding multiple elements from one string

Tags: php

I have the following code which is being stored inside of a string.

```
<ol class="tracklist">
    <li class="track" data-file="https://www48.zippyshare.com/music/BCFNtvU9/0/file.mp3" data-index="0">
      <a class="title name" href="#"><span class="name">1. MI Abaga - Do you know who you are_ Take some time and meditate on you</span></a>
      <ul class="actions">
        <li>
          <a href=https://www41.zippyshare.com/v/BCFNtvU9/file.html" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-arrow-down mobile-only-ib"></span>
          <span class="text desktop-only-ib">Download</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="track" data-file="https://www41.zippyshare.com/music/FLCe2uFJ/0/file.mp3" data-index="1">
      <a class="title name" href="#"><span class="name">2. MI Abaga - Last Night I Had A Dream About A Hummingbird</span></a>
      <ul class="actions">
        <li>
          <a href="https://www41.zippyshare.com/v/FLCe2uFJ/file.html" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-arrow-down mobile-only-ib"></span>
          <span class="text desktop-only-ib">Download</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The string for this example will be called `$audio` the string contains the above data, and I am trying to remove the portions which contain `https://wwwRANDOMNUMBER.zippyshare.com/v/RANDOM-ID/file.html` and then use a [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) on them to programatically hide all of the file links from users, until they click through.

How can I go about replacing the existing content with an encoded version?

Comment: Personally I'd use `DOMDocument` and work your way from there. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the (implied) second question you have, which is how to decode the base64 after the user clicks.  But to encode them in the first place:

```
preg_match_all('#(https://www\d+.zippyshare\.com/(?:[^"]+))#',$audio, $matches);

foreach ( $matches as $match )
{
    $encoded = base64_encode($match[1]);
    $audio = str_replace($match[1], $encoded, $audio);
}
```